# Center with margin auto doesn't work

Tags: css, margin

I use a jQuery animation in my page which adds some CSS properties and I don't understand why the `margin: auto` doesn't work.

The HTML code (with style properties added by jQuery) :

```
<body style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="tuto_wamp" style="width: 7680px; height: 923px; ">
        <!-- Step 1 -->
        <div style="height: 549px; width: 1280px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; position: absolute; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; ">
            <div class="content_tuto">
                <img src="images/install1.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS code :

```
#tuto_wamp 
{ 
    background: #3a393c;
    width: 100%;
}

.content_tuto
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

I don't know which property blocks the `margin: auto` to center the image.

Thank you.

Comment: Which browser(s) are you testing?

Comment: Chrome Firefox and Opera

Comment: width:100%, margin:auto; I dont ger your question clearly, please http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don't understand what you want Shibin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `text-align:center;` to `.content_tuto` and it will center

Note, you have the widths `style="width: 7680px;  ...` and `style=".. width: 1280px; ...` , so when you center you are centering for that width.

Comment: Because you want the margin to be on the image with display block instead of the div, check this one http://jsfiddle.net/xVNbQ/1/

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old post, but wanted to share how i solved the same problem.

My image was inheriting a `float:left` from a parent class. By setting `float:none` I was able to make `margin:0 auto` work properly. Hope it may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

it won't work because you've set the width of `.content_tuto` to `100%;`

Comment: Which one ? In the tuto_wamp or in .content_tuto ?

Comment: How can you have "an equal amount of margin on each side" of something that has NO margin on each side? If you are 100% wide then you fill ALL the space, therefore both side margins are 0. You can't center a box who is 100% wide.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle and added a border to visualise and solve

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/Y42Pf/

You could also have a good read of center a div in css from here

http://stever.ca/web-design/centering-a-div-in-ie8-using-marginauto/

Hope it helps.